# MobileFIrst support for High resolutions

Tags: iphone, resolution, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

We are building our application for MFP 7.1 using command line which has been migrated from WL 6.2.

In our Iphone 6 and 6+ the screens are appearing with low resolutions. We faced this issue before on WL 6.2 and IBM had to provide iFix for our CLI to compile the project with High resolution.

MFP Version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

Are we missing an iFix or do we need to open PMR for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen these articles, which provide instructions for what seems to be your issue:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_images_ios.html
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/03/19/support-iphone-66-plus-compatible-application-resolution-mobilefirst-platform-v6-3-earlier/

For 7.1 this is built-in, so make sure to handle the plist file as instructed above.

Comment: Thank you, I assigned our UI developer to work on this.